# Error CS0103 The name 'peremennaya_slozenie' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, windows, windows-10, win-universal-app

I already have cathced this error, and I tried how to solve it, but ineffectually.

I have this code:

```
 public void button_plus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int peremennaya_slozenie= Convert.ToInt32(ekran.Text);
    }

    private void button_rvno_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ekran.Text = Convert.ToString(peremennaya_slozenie + Convert.ToInt32(ekran.Text));
    }
```

And I want to use `peremennaya_slozenie` from method `button_plus_Click` in method `button_rvno_Click`. How can I do a stuff like that?

Comment: The error is self-explanatory. peremennaya_slozenie is in scope of button_plus_Click not button_rvno_Click .Use a property in form class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move declaration of the `peremennaya_slozenie` variable to the class level:

```
private int peremennaya_slozenie;

public void button_plus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    peremennaya_slozenie = Convert.ToInt32(ekran.Text);
}

private void button_rvno_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ekran.Text = Convert.ToString(peremennaya_slozenie + Convert.ToInt32(ekran.Text));
}
```

Comment: It now gets a warning:
Severity Code Description Project File Line
Warning CS0649 Field 'MainPage.peremennaya_slozenie' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value 0 Калькулятор c:\users\богдан лашков\onedrive\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Калькулятор\Калькулятор\MainPage.xaml.cs 103

Comment: Please pay attention that in the `button_plus_Click` method there is no variable declaration (there is no `int` keyword).